# Snapshot in cassandra driver

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

I am trying to take snapshot of a `cassandra cluster` from a node which do not have `cassandra` installed, i.e. a node which is not a part of the cluster(so cannot use nodetool) . I am thinking of using cassandra driver 3.0.0 to do this.

The documentation http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/index.html has no mention of any api to take the snapshot.

So should I assume that currently it is not possible to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using the native protocol drivers. You would need to use a JMX client, which is what nodetool uses to invoke that method.

Personally I would put Cassandra on the machine on which you want to run the command, and use nodetool. It could be as simple as grabbing the tarball distribution if you don't want to install with a package manager.

Answer (score 1):

The drivers do not have a way to trigger a snapshot.  However, it's possible to trigger a snapshot remotely through JMX.  Nodetool is generally the easiest way to do this.  It can be used from a machine that is not running Cassandra -- just download a Cassandra tarball that matches the version of your cluster, and use the nodetool that's included in that.

You may also need to change the configuration of your Cassandra cluster (in `cassandra-env.sh`) to enable remote JMX connections.  However, if you do this, please be aware of the [security implications](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/JmxSecurity).

Comment: Also if there are different version of cassandra  running in the nodes of a cluster and we need to use one node from which we would like to take all backup (using nodetool) , will nodetool have any issues ?

Comment: user3351750 - if you have different versions of cassandra in the same cluster, you are going to have other problems. One of your top priorities should probably be to bring all nodes to the same version. e.g., the format of sstables can be changed between versions. nodetool -h <hostname> can then be used to snapshot. best idea is to use a tool to run snapshot on all nodes simultaneously.